# "super of super" in extented classes (alter variable in super class of super class)

Tags: java, android

The question is more Java, but I want to implement it in Android:

Suppose there are 3 or more classes extending each other:

```
class A {
    ...
    int color;
    ...
}

class B extends A {
    ...
}

class C extends B {
    ...
    // I want to alter color of class A inside here
}
```

Is this possible without setting a `super.color = 4` in `C` and setting another `color=4` and `super.color = 4` in `B`??

e.g. is it possible to write something like `super(super(color=3))` within class C ?

Answer (score 2):

```
...
// I want to alter color of class A inside here
...
```

Non-private fields are inherited to the subclasses. You can just do `color = 3` in `C` and it will affect `A.color`.

Comment: Hehe, yes, that should be sufficient. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please upvote useful answers and accept the one solving your issue.

Comment: Access modifiers don't affect inheritance, only visibility.

Comment: yes, but visibility affect access. a private field cannot be accessed from outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible through the constructors - you can only invoke the immediate super constructor.

But you can reassign the field with `color=3` after the call the `super()`